# Soundcloud API get only permalink_url

Tags: soundcloud, permalinks

How can I get the **permalink_url** only of using Soundcloud API tracks?
It returns all fields.

How am I able to return only the **permalink_url**?

I tried this but no luck: I tried this but no luck: http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=XX&q=Charlie%20Puth&limit=100&fields=permalink_url

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to parse the returned JSON for the permalink_url. Something like:

```
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(tracksJSON);
var permalink = parsedJSON.permalink_url;
```

If you have jQuery, I believe $.getJSON automatically parses the info for you as well. I hope this helps you!